# Use Ubuntu-server as RDP gateway

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, iptables, gateway, ubuntu-22.04

I need to reach a win10-machine (10.7.3.23) via an ubuntu-server (10.15.0.12).
Via VPN I can reach an ubuntu-server, but not the win10-machine. The ubuntu-server can reach the Win10-machine via port 3389. From internal network the RDP access to win10-machine is working.
What I did so far:
The firewall of the network is open on port 3389.
On the ubuntu-server:

I opened the port 3389 at the ufw:
`sudo ufw status`

````
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
...
3389/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3389/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
10.7.3.0/24 22             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
10.7.3.0/24 3389           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere ```

The first two lines allow the incoming access from vpn. the last two lines allow the access from ubuntu-server to win10-machine.

I added the following lines at /etc/ufw/before.rules to route the access 3389 to the win 10 machine (10.7.3.23).
```*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
#forward rdp to cbs-rechner
-A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT \ --to-destination 10.7.3.23:3389
-A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p udp --dport 3389 -j DNAT \ --to-destination 10.7.3.23:3389
#setup routing
-A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
````

The output of `sudo iptables -nL` is

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
...

ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-user-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-user-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-user-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3389
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3389

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.7.3.0/24          tcp dpt:3389
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.7.3.0/24          udp dpt:3389
```

To connect to the RDP on the win10-machine, i dial into vpn and use the rdp-connection-software of windows:
[settings in RDP-connection-software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbiTs.png)

I also tried the socat command, without any success.
`socat -d TCP4-LISTEN:3389,reuseaddr TCP4:10.7.3.23:3389`

Does someone has a clue how to get/debug the connection?
thank you in advance